# In Object-Oriented Javascript pass object member method to event handler

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

In Javascript I have defined an object like this:

```
function myObject() {
    this.x = 5;
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler);
}

myObject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert(this.x);
}

myObject.prototype.resizeHandler = function() {
    this.doSomething();   // Here occurs error.
}

var obj = new myObject();
```

However I am running into the error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Question is "why is that?" Explanation would be great!

Comment: *"Explanation would be great!"* The explanation is that you're passing the function and not the object. Functions themselves are objects and can be passed around and referenced like any other object. Because of this, you could have multiple objects reference the same function, or no object referencing it. There's no such thing as an "owner" object. Because the value of `this` in a function is generally based on how that function is invoked, you need to invoke it in such a way that you, implicitly or explicitly, "tell" the function what its `this` value should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the context of `this` is correct...

```
function myObject() {
    this.x = 5;
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler.bind(this));
}

myObject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert(this.x);
}

myObject.prototype.resizeHandler = function() {
    this.doSomething();   // Here occurs error.
}
```

Here the `.bind(this)` is used.

The `this` changes in the function used as an event handler.

Comment: Small footnote: #bind is not supported in IE < 9. A polyfill is available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility

Comment: Thanks, meant to mention that too... :)